# CSS Ellipsis is underscore not ... for certain font

Tags: css

I am using css ellipsis as follows:

```
.test {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 170px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: "Edmondsans Regular",sans-serif;
}
```

It works perfectly but, the should be resulting **...** changes to **_** when using font: **Edmondsans Regular**

Why would a particular font do that? More importantly how can I get it to **NOT** do that.

Comment: Perhaps because the ellipsis character is not defined in its valid code point in the font?

Comment: can you make a fiddle with the font in use?

Comment: So what does that font have as glyph for the ellipsis character (e.g. when you test in a text editor or word processor)? The most obvious explanation is that the font has a wrong glyph. If this is not the case, please post a complete testable page and specify where the font used is available.

Comment: Or the dots in the ellipses are simply too close together at that font size and font weight. What happens if you try a larger font size and lighter weight?